# How to use UnityResolver in Console App?

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have the following resolver in my WebApi project:

```
 config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container); // HttpConfiguration config
```

However in a console app, I don't have HttpContiguration.  How can I tell my unity container to use this DependencyResolver from my console app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There might be a better way, but I do my registrations, and then let the container resolve my *"first"* class.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Registering dependencies ...");
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ProgramStarter, ProgramStarter>(); // Register a class that continues your program.

        // Do your registrations.
        RegisterTypes(container);

        // Let Unity resolve ProgramStarter and create a build plan.
        var program = container.Resolve<ProgramStarter>();

        Console.WriteLine("All done. Starting program...");
        program.Run();
    }
}
```

And my `ProgramStarter` class.

```
public class ProgramStarter
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public ProgramStarter(IService service)
    {
        // Unity has created this instance and resolved all dependencies.
        _service= service;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // Do what you want to do.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't. The `UnityResolver` exists to interact with the MVC framework. A console application is no framework and there are no framework types that a Console Application tries to create for you. Since there is no framework, no special hooks are required to use a DI container in a console application. You simply create the container and have one `container.Resolve` call to construct the object graph and call the method on the resolved object.